# Number of ways to arrange 6 digit number with 8 given digits

Tags: permutations, combinations

I recently started learning about Combinations and Permutations and I got this question:

> A is a group of natural numbers with 6 digit, that can be assembled from the digits 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
> a. How many numbers are in A?
> b. In how many numbers in A the digit 1 occur *at most* once?
> c. In how many numbers in A the digit 1 occur *at most* once
> *and* the digit 2 doesn't occur at all?
> d. In how many numbers 1 shows exactly once?

so the first one I got, every digit in the number have 8 options to choose from and that's why it's $8^6$.
but I started get confused with b, I thought that since 1 can show at most once then it means that one digit have 8 options while the others have 7 which makes it: $8*7^5$
apparently it's not, can you explain the way I'm supposed to approach this kind of questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (b) there are two possibilities:  either $1$ doesn't occur at all, or it occurs only once.  Use the analysis from (a) to figure out how many such numbers there are in which $1$ doesn't occur at all.

To figure out how many numbers have $1$ occur exactly once, you have $6$ choices for the location of the $1$.  Once you've picked that location, again, use the analysis you used in part (a) to figure out how many such numbers there are with $1$ in that location.  Then multiply by $6$ (because there are $6$ possible locations for the $1$).  Don't forget to add back in the number of possibilities in which $1$ doesn't occur at all to get the answer to (b).

That should be enough to help you figure out (c) and (d).

Comment: Thank you! so I figured the answer is $(7^6)+(7^5)*6$ 
I still didn't understand where I was wrong in my initial approach ?

Comment: You didn't analyze *which* digit has $8$ options.  Your answer works out to $7^6+7^5$.